# Regex return expected result plus line break on another line

Tags: php, regex, csv

Before I start, I know this is CSV and I know there is a function that exist build-in PHP.
I got the following pattern :

`preg_match_all("/([^\"]|\"[^\"]*\")*?(r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/i", $CSV, $Matches);`

Who will parse something like that :

```
Country,Region/State,City,"Zip/Postal Code\n From","Zip/Postal Code To","Weight From","Weight To","Shipping Price","Delivery Type"\n\r
CAN,*,,,,0.0000,4999.0000,29.7500,Priority\n\r
CAN,*,,,,10000.0000,19999.0000,35.5000,Express\n\r
CAN,*,,,,0.0000,4999.0000,19.7500,Express\n\r
CAN,*,,,,20000.0000,99999999.9999,59.0000,Priority\n\r
CAN,*,,,,5000.0000,9999.0000,34.7500,Priority\n\r
CAN,*,,,,20000.0000,99999999.9999,41.5000,Express\n\r
CAN,*,,,,5000.0000,9999.0000,24.4500,Express\n\r
CAN,*,,,,10000.0000,19999.0000,48.0000,Priority\n\r
CAN,*,,,,10000.0000,19999.0000,29.7500,Standard\n\r
CAN,*,,,,20000.0000,99999999.9999,36.5000,Standard\n\r
CAN,*,,,,500.0000,9999.0000,20.3500,Standard\n\r
CAN,*,,,,90.0000,499.0000,9.7500,Standard\n\r
CAN,*,,,,50.0000,89.0000,1.8000,Standard\n\r
CAN,*,,,,30.0000,49.0000,1.5000,Standard\n\r
CAN,*,,,,0.0000,29.0000,1.0000,Standard\n\r
USA,*,,,,20000.0000,99999999.9999,160.0000,Express\n\r
USA,*,,,,10000.0000,14999.0000,76.0000,Express\n\r
USA,*,,,,1000.0000,4999.0000,42.0000,Express\n\r
USA,*,,,,15000.0000,19999.0000,155.0000,Priority\n\r
USA,*,,,,5000.0000,9999.0000,94.0000,Priority\n\r
USA,*,,,,0.0000,999.0000,75.5000,Priority\n\r
USA,*,,,,15000.0000,19999.0000,98.0000,Express\n\r
USA,*,,,,5000.0000,9999.0000,61.5000,Express\n\r
USA,*,,,,0.0000,999.0000,40.0000,Express\n\r
USA,*,,,,20000.0000,99999999.9999,230.0000,Priority\n\r
USA,*,,,,10000.0000,14999.0000,120.0000,Priority\n\r
USA,*,,,,1000.0000,4999.0000,61.5000,Priority\n\r
USA,*,,,,500.0000,999.0000,25.5000,Standard\n\r
USA,*,,,,90.0000,499.0000,13.3500,Standard\n\r
USA,*,,,,50.0000,89.0000,3.0000,Standard\n\r
USA,*,,,,30.0000,49.0000,1.8000,Standard\n\r
USA,*,,,,0.0000,29.0000,1.5000,Standard\n\r
```

The resulst I get is similar to :

```
[2] => Array
    (
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => CAN
        [1] => *
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => 
        [5] => 10000.0000
        [6] => 19999.0000
        [7] => 35.5000
    )

[4] => Array
    (
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => CAN
        [1] => *
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => 
        [5] => 0.0000
        [6] => 4999.0000
        [7] => 19.7500
    )

[6] => Array
    (
    )
```

If I try to add `?:` in the line break group it still do it. Can anyone help me, I am stuck there. Thanks.

Comment: If you know that, why aren't you using it?

Comment: What strange kind of newlines is that? I've never seen `\n\r` before. Also (possibly related?) your regex is missing a backslash before `r`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Oups, I added the backslash. Thanks for noticing. `\n\r` is just a possibilities that can happen. I made my class to be used for beginner. Also to add, the sub-array is generated by a while on each char (instead of regex) to extract everything by the separator (,) not between double-quote.

Comment: *Where*  can `\n\r` happen? I know of no operating system that uses this as a newline standard, but I'm happy to learn more.

Comment: @TimPietzcker This can happen, not by the OS, but the programmer behind the screen. I created another class that can create CSV from an array and you can tell what will be the line break at the end of each line. Thoses class are made for a class so they can learn what regex do and how to avoid it using different method (looping on each char of a string let's say) and building standard CSV using class method (instead of an easy function build-in).

Comment: @TimPietzcker @David I'd have to think that matching `\n\r` as a newline could get you into trouble. If it consumed `\n` from the end of one line and then `\r` from the beginning of the next line (if it happened to be blank), wouldn't you lose that  line, which might have had significance? (Not in this example, of course.)

Comment: @CarlWalsh You are right. The `\n\r` was causing problem in a certain way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing any particulars of php matching, I'll take your word that the regex is working like you show it is (using [my preferred regex](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) I'm not capturing in the same way).

*I'll assume you are trying to remove those blank matches.* I'll also believe that those "newlines" are actually encoded into the input, and not left as literal `\`'s and `\r`'s and `\n`'s.

The problem seems to be the "newlines" are being matched twice? Like you match just the `\n` on one pass, and then the `\r` on the next pass?

The simplest solution would be to restrict the newline to be the type you know the file has: `/([^\"]|\"[^\"]*\")*?(\n\r)/`
Does this help?

Alternatively, I would **just use a regex split (delimited by comma)** on each line of input.

Comment: No the regex above just give a simple row of the subarray... I am creating the subarray like I said using programmation instead of regex. I will check your solution tomorrow at work. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I tested it. It was useful but I didn't use your solution. The problem was: first of all, I was wrong in my OP post. I really needed to use `?:` to not return the result. I also add to use `\r\n` first, then `\n` and `\r`. The group `\n\r` has been removed. Thanks for leading me.